# JSF PrimeFaces 6.1 p:gmap does not render polylines using Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

For a project requirement, I need to render polylines using the primefaces 6.1 p:gmap tag but only the map gets rendered. Here is my XHTML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=SOME_KEY" defer="defer"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="gmap/gmap.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:form id="form1">
            <p:gmap center="36.883707, 30.689216" zoom="15" type="MAP" style="width:900px;height:800px;"
                    model="#{mapBean.model}" id="myMap"/>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and here is my Bean

```
import org.primefaces.model.map.DefaultMapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.LatLng;
import org.primefaces.model.map.MapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.Polyline;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import java.io.Serializable;

@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "mapBean")
public class MapBean implements Serializable {

    private MapModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void MapBean() {
        model = new DefaultMapModel();
        Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
        polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648));
        polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216));
        polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707));
        polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323));

        polyline.setStrokeWeight(8);
        polyline.setStrokeColor("#FF9900");
        polyline.setStrokeOpacity(0.9);

        model.addOverlay(polyline);
    }

    public MapModel getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }
}
```

The polylines added to the MapBean model do not get displayed by the p:gmap attribute. Only the map gets displayed. I am running primefaces 6.1 with Mojarra 2.2.11 using Spring Boot 1.2.3. Any ideas / pointers to anything I may be missing or is it a genuine issue with p:gmap and polyline rendering ? I have also looked in the Chrome Javascript console and there is no error displayed.

Comment: Works great here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/polylines.xhtml find the differences

Comment: Oh and you miss a scope declaration on your bean. And `<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="gmap/gmap.js" />` is in the wrong place (it is outside the `h:head`)

Comment: @Kukeltje I have done the changes (see original code post edited with the changes) but still it does not render the polylines. I am following the example from the primefaces link you posted. Are you able to try at your end and let know if it works or any other pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Thanks @Kukeltje for your help.
It seems that when we are using the Spring Framework (I am using SpringBoot 1.2.3 to run this app) to manage things, we need to used the **@Named** annotation for the Bean which is to server the model.

Here is the change I did for it to work.

The XHTML stays the same as in original code post (above)
The Bean code (which worked is as below)

```
import org.primefaces.model.map.DefaultMapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.LatLng;
import org.primefaces.model.map.MapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.Polyline;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named("mapBean")
public class MapBean implements Serializable {
    public void setModel(MapModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    private MapModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void MapBean() {
        model = new DefaultMapModel();
        Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
        polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648));
        polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216));
        polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707));
        polyline.getPaths().add(new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323));
        polyline.setStrokeWeight(8);
        polyline.setStrokeColor("#FF9900");
        polyline.setStrokeOpacity(0.9);
        model.addOverlay(polyline);
    }
    public MapModel getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }
}
```

[image]